# Java - comparación en la condicion de 'if' con un método existente

Tags: java, condiciones

Tengo un método que es el siguiente:

```
private static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

Quiero añadirlo como condición dentro del 'if'

Pretendo sustituir este código que actualmente tengo:

```
if (!Character.isAlphabetic(character)) {       
                result.append(character);
                continue;
}
```

Y no sé cómo hacerlo. el planteamiento que tengo es este:

```
if (!this.ALPHABET(character)){
                result.append(character);
                continue;
}
```

El error mostrado es `Method call expected`

La alternativa que he visto es poner en vez de `this`, el nombre de la clase: `!Code1.ALPHABET(character)`, pero el error sigue siendo el mismo.

Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Eso es un objeto String, no un método.

Comment: @PabloLozano, y como puedo emplearlo dentro de la condición?

Comment: debes llamar a algún método de esa instancia, por ejemplo ALPHABET.contains

Comment: @PabloLozano, gracias. Dices así, si? ```!ALPHABET.contains(character)```  Claro, aquí entonces tengo el fallo de *java.lang.string cannot be applied to char* Tengo entonces que pasar a string lo de dentro del parentesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que has creado no es un método, sino un objeto `String` que contiene las letras del alfabeto (sólo en minúsculas) y que tiene varios métodos que podrías usar para comprobar que un caracter existe. Lo más sencillo sería algo como

```java
if (ALPHABET.indexOf(character) == -1) {
   ...
}
```

El método indexOf devuelve el valor del índice (la posición) en la que se encuentra el caracter dado (la primera ocurrencia), pero si no se encuentra en todo el texto devuelve -1

Si buscaras un texto (substring), entonces podrías usar, además de indexOf, el método contains, que devuelve true o false